# Android Studio - no sources/javadocs for Android core libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently installed Android Studio 3.3, and I have both **Android SDK Platform 28** and **Sources for Android 28** (both under Android 9.0) installed. But Android studio does not actually detect the sources for any of the Android library classes, and as such I cannot view their javadocs or read their sources.

To be specific, my app `build.gradle` looks roughly like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    // other stuff...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.11'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
}
```

The libraries at the bottom like the Kotlin standard library, Glide, OkHttp, FlexBox and so on come with their sources so I have no problem there. But the libraries at the top do not have any sources attached. So the classes in `android.app`, `android.support.v4.app` and other Android packages have no javadocs when I click on them, and when I try to view the sources, AS decompiles the class file instead.

```
Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 51.0 (Java 7)
```

Choosing to `Download Sources` isn't having any effect, and I don't want to have to manually choose the sources, because I never needed to do that before upgrading the IDE. The app still builds without any problems, it's just those missing sources that are the issue. Is there a way to make Android Studio automatically detect the sources and fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In android studio click `file -> Sync with file system`
this should help, try to close the file and reopen after the sync.
if not help try to `file -> Invalidate caches and restart`